# $L\log L$ and $L^p$ embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

My question is a simple one: I am aware of the embedding $L^p(\Omega)\in L\log L(\Omega)$ for finite measure spaces, with constant $\frac{cp}{p-1}$. Does this embedding hold on for instance, the whole of $\mathcal{R}^n$, and what is the constant in the norm estimates? Would it blow up as $|\Omega|\rightarrow\infty$ and $p\rightarrow 1$ as well?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Does this embedding hold on for instance, the whole of R n  , " $\rightarrow$ Does this embedding hold on for instance, the whole of R n  ,  with lebesgue measure .  It does not.  In $\mathbb R^1$. e.g., take any sequence $a_n > 0$ that is square summable but not LlogL summable, $a_n = 1/n$ will do.  Then take the step function equal to $a_n, n < x < n+1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused because in the Interpolation of Operators book by Bennett and Sharpley they treat the proof as a general case with unbounded sets.

Comment: Sorry mike, one more thing: $1/n$ is square summable on $(1,\infty)$ but not locally $L^2$ on $(0,1)$. For this embedding to be true on balls containing zero, wouldn't we need an example like $n^{-1/3}$?

Answer (score 1):

The embedding $L^p(\Omega)\subset L\log L(\Omega)$ does not hold on spaces of infinite measure. An example was given by [mike](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661942/l-log-l-and-lp-embedding#comment1392872_661942) in a comment: define 
$$
f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[n,n+1)}
$$
then $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for every $p>1$, not $f\notin L\log L(\mathbb R)$.

Generally, let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two Orlicz functions. Examples similar to the one above show that to infer the integrability of $\phi(|f|)$ from the integrability of $\psi(|f|)$, one needs $\phi(t)=O(\psi(t))$ as $t\to0$ and as $t\to\infty$. On a space of finite measure,  $\phi(t)=O(\psi(t))$ as  $t\to\infty$ suffices, since we do not need to worry about small values of $f$.